# How to implement BufferedReader readLine method with max number of characters?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I need a `BufferedReader` method that will either stop at a newline or when it reaches the maximum number of characters read.

```
String readLine(int maxCharacters) throws IOException;
```

What's the best way to implement this functionality?

The reason for this method is to prevent `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions, like:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3647" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:535)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:322)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:363)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
```

Comment: Wrap the `BufferedReader` in a *CustomClass*. Implement `read() / readLine()` in CustomClass and implement logic to check number of chars read.

Comment: That's not a proper way to prevent an `OOME`. You shouldn't be reading lines from huge files that don't consist of lines.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm reading lines from a stream, so I can't tell how big the lines will be. What's the proper way to prevent an `OOME`?

Comment: If you're reading a stream, you're not really reading lines. What are you doing with those characters?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm putting the lines into an HTML report, each in its own `<span/>`

Comment: If you're running out of memory, you've got one huge line coming. That's probably not something that you should be receiving or putting into a HTML report. There is a bigger bug involved here.

Comment: @Kayaman This is a corner case. The user sending the stream is sending bad data, but I need to handle it so the application doesn't crash.

Comment: Then don't use readLine(). Either create your own subclass that allows you to specify the max line size, or read chars. If it's HTML it doesn't matter what it looks like in the source anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a local copy of [BufferedReader](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html) and append something like the following at the bottom of the `bufferLoop` in the `readLine(boolean ignoreLF)` method:

```
if (s.length() > MAX_CHARACTERS) {
    throw new IOException("Next line is longer than " + MAX_CHARACTERS
            + " characters.");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `read(char[] buf)` Method instead and set the size of the char Array to your max value;

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    String path = "asdf.txt";

    BufferedWriter write = null;
    try {
        write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
        write.write("This is a Test");

        write.flush();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    write.close();


    try {
        FileReader read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader re = new BufferedReader(read);


        char[] ar = new char[8];

        re.read(ar);

        re.close();
        read.close();

        System.out.println(new String(ar));

        //System.out.println(r);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}
```

Comment: That won't work without storing the result of the read() method into a variable, as you have to check for -1 and otherwise use it as the byte count.